# Invalid Bundle Error When App Store Connect Processes Build

Tags: ios, xcode10.2, app-store-connect

I'm getting the following error after my app has processed in `AppStore Connect`.

"ITMS-90562: Invalid Bundle - The app submission can not be successfully recompiled from bitcode due to missing symbols during linking. You can try to reproduce and diagnose such issues locally by following the instructions from:
`enter code here`https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2432/_index.html"

I did an AdHoc export as the above link recommends and was **not** able to reproduce the issue. This is with `Xcode 10.2` with an app that includes a watch extension and several other extensions. Many previous builds of the app have been submitted successfully. As recently as last week. I even went back to the commit of the last known good submission, increased the build number and uploaded that with the same results. I started seeing this problem on Friday September 13. My instincts are telling me this is most likely a bug with AppStore Connect. Is anyone else experiencing this same problem or have advice about how to work around it?

Comment: I would just turn off bitcode. It’s just a needless extra pain point anyway.

Comment: The app has a watch extension which requires bitcode so we can't turn it off across the board. Turning bitcode off for the just the iOS targets results in the same invalid bundle error.